# How to create a relationship between User and Posts in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a blog and want to include the Users Name when shown to the public.

When creating the blog I make sure to include the `user_id` in the `blogs table`

**In my Blog model I have the following:**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**In my Users model I have:**

```
public function blogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Blog::class);
}
```

**In my Blog Controller I have:**

```
public function index(User $user)
{
    $users = User::get();
   $blogs= DB::table('blogs')->where('user_id', '=', $users->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(6);
   return view('blogs.index',compact('blogs'));
}
```

**Then in my view:**

```
@foreach($blogs as $blog)
<h1>{{$blog->title}}</h1>
Source:{{$blog->users->first_name}} // This does not work
Source:{{$blog->first_name}} // This does not work either
@endforeach
```

I thought I could do something like this to show the names:

```
{{ $blogs->users->first_name }} {{ $blogs->users->last_name }}
```

But this isn't working either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@foreach($blogs as $blog)
<h1>{{$blog->title}}</h1>
{{$blog->user->first_name}} 

@endforeach
```

And on your Blog Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: Tried this solution, and the one above, but no luck. Not sure where I'm going wrong with the `User` `Blog` relationship, but I not able to get the blog author with only the `user_id` in the Blogs tables. A quick fix would be to add the authors name to the blog table, but really think there is a better solution.

Comment: Can you show me your migration? The solutions above should have worked.And Take a look at the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: I edit my solution, try i again. It will probably work now

Comment: The edited solution worked. Does `users` have to be `user` due to `users` being  a reserved word? Just curious. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, in this case the correct is the relation be named user() because the blog has one user (One to many (inverse) relationship) and the user has many blogs (One to many relationship). You can find more info about this in the link in the comment above. Glad i could help :)

Comment: Hey, I have a question about this relationship, I am a bit confused between ```$user->posts``` and ```$user->posts()``` which to use and when to use, and what is the difference between these two methods?

Comment: @DevsBuddy , you should use ``$user->posts`` because it's an eloquent's dynamic property. Dynamic properties allow you to access relationship methods as if they were properties defined on the model. So basically `` posts()`` is the method and ``posts`` the dynamic property. I strongly recommend you to ask this question here in SO, so it can be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: @Piazzi I tried but sometimes it shows an error sometimes it works I mean sometimes it is working using method way but sometimes it is working using property way that's why it is making me confuse I am pasting some code here.

This is working
```auth()->user()->transactions()->whereType('income')->sum('amount')```
this is not
```auth()->user()->transactions->whereType('income')->sum('amount')```

this is working 
```auth()->user()->transactions->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->limit(1)->first();```
this is not
```auth()->user()->transactions()->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->limit(1)->first();```

Answer (score 2):

In your Blog controller, the variable `$blog` needs to be `$blogs.` You also have extra characters (right parenthesis) in your Blade. It should be:

```
@foreach($blogs as $blog)
    <h1>{{ $blog->title }}</h1>
    Source: {{ $blog->user->first_name }} {{ $blog->user->last_name }}
@endforeach
```

**Blog Model**

This function replaces the old "users" function, as only one user is returned (belongsTo is a singular relationship).

```
class Blog extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function blogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Blog::class);
}
```

**Controller Function**

As such, you can reduce your controller code by removing redundant elements.

```
public function index(User $user)
{
   $blogs = Blog::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);

   return view('blogs.index', compact('blogs'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you did is called Query Builder

```
$blogs= DB::table('blogs')->where('user_id', '=', $users->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(6);
```

Query Builder does not support lazy loading, cause lazy loading is only supported for the Eloquent method

```
$blog->users->first_name
```

For Eloquent way you can try this instead:

```
$blogs = Blog::where('user_id', $user->id)->get()
foreach($blogs as $blog){
    dd($blog->user); // you will get the user detail here
}
```

For lazy loading have a performance issue when come to load heavy data so to prevent lazy loading can use this

```
$blogs = Blog::with('user')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get()
```

For more information can look at [Eloquent Relationship Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

For query builder, the only way to link your user is use join, which will be something like this

```
$blogs = DB::table('blogs')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'blogs.user_id')
        ->get();

foreach($blogs as $blog){
    dd($blog->first_name) // user first name
}
```

For more information can look at [Query Builder Join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins)

Comment: When I do it the Eloquent way as you explain, the page renders, but no data is added to the view. I get `Collection {#888 ▼
  #items: []
}` on my `dd($blogs)`

Comment: probably you are using `$users = User::all()` if you want to get all blog then just `$blog = Blog::all()` then

Comment: I see.. This works `$blogs = Blog::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);
   return view('blogs.index',compact('blogs'));`

Answer (score 0):

**BlogController.php**

```
public function index(){
      $blogs = Blog::with('user')->get();
      return view('blogs.index')->with('blogs',$blogs);
}
```

**Blog.php**

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

**User.php**

```
public function blogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Blog');
}
```